# CakePHP3.4: don't understand error saving a belongsToMany association

Tags: cakephp-3.4

I try to input a `belongsToMany` association in a Form but a quite particular association description.
Because my entity `Site` can use Languages for 2 different usages, I use 2 join tables.
So the schema is the following

```
Relationship                        Join Table Fields
Sites belongsToMany Vislanguages    sites_vislanguages.id, sites_vislanguages.language_id, sites_vislanguages.site_id
Relationship                        Join Table Fields
Sites belongsToMany Reclanguages    sites_reclanguages.id, sites_reclanguages.language_id, sites_reclanguages.site_id
```

So the `Table` classes are:

```
class VislanguagesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('languages');
        $this->displayField('name_fr');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsToMany('Sites', [
            'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'site_id',
            'joinTable' => 'sites_vislanguages',
        ]);

    }
}

class SitesTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->belongsToMany('Reclanguages', [
        'joinTable' => 'sites_reclanguages',
        'className' => 'Languages',
        'propertyName' => 'reclanguages'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Vislanguages', [
        'joinTable' => 'sites_vislanguages',
        'className' => 'Languages',
        'propertyName' => 'vislanguages'
    ]);

}
```

class SitesVislanguagesTable extends Table {

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('sites_vislanguages');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Sites', [
        'foreignKey' => 'site_id',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Languages', [
        'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
    ]);
}
```

I of course have the problem for `add` and `edit` forms, but I here take the example of `edit`.
If I `find()` a ready made `site`, the data structure is:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

    'id' => (int) 23098,
    'Vislanguages' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Language) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\SitesVislanguage) {

                'id' => (int) 4409,
                'site_id' => (int) 23098,
                'language_id' => (int) 1,
                ...,
                '[repository]' => 'SitesVislanguages'

            },
            ...,
            '[repository]' => 'Vislanguages'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Language) {

            'id' => (int) 9,
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\SitesVislanguage) {

                'id' => (int) 4410,
                'site_id' => (int) 23098,
                'language_id' => (int) 9,
                ...,
                '[repository]' => 'SitesVislanguages'

            },
            ...,
            '[repository]' => 'Vislanguages'

        }
    ],
    ...,
    '[repository]' => 'Sites'

}
```

And my corresponding `ctp` file is:

```
<?= $this->Form->control('vislanguages._ids', ['options' => $languages, 'label' => __('Spoken languages:'), 'multiple' => true]); ?>
```

The languages are correctly preselected in the input.
If I submit it without any change, the patched entity is:

object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

```
'id' => (int) 23098,
...,
'vislanguages' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Language) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        ...,
        '[repository]' => 'Vislanguages'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Language) {

        'id' => (int) 9,
        ...,
        '[repository]' => 'Vislanguages'

    }
],
'[repository]' => 'Sites'
```

}

Which seems to be correct but when I save it, I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vislanguage_id' in 'where clause'
```

The query is:

```
(SELECT SitesVislanguages.id AS `SitesVislanguages__id`, SitesVislanguages.site_id AS `SitesVislanguages__site_id`, SitesVislanguages.language_id AS `SitesVislanguages__language_id` FROM sites_vislanguages SitesVislanguages WHERE (site_id = :c0 AND vislanguage_id = :c1))
UNION (SELECT SitesVislanguages.id AS `SitesVislanguages__id`, SitesVislanguages.site_id AS `SitesVislanguages__site_id`, SitesVislanguages.language_id AS `SitesVislanguages__language_id` FROM sites_vislanguages SitesVislanguages WHERE (site_id = :c2 AND vislanguage_id = :c3))
```

Why do we see `vislanguage_id` in the `WHERE` clause whereas it correctly considers `language_id` instead in the `SELECT` clause ?

In the same time, I don't really understand the `UNION` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it working, I had to specify the `targetForeignKey`:

```
class SitesTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->belongsToMany('Reclanguages', [
        'targetForeignKey' => 'language_id,
        'joinTable' => 'sites_reclanguages',
        'className' => 'Languages',
        'propertyName' => 'reclanguages'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Vislanguages', [
        'targetForeignKey' => 'language_id,
        'joinTable' => 'sites_vislanguages',
        'className' => 'Languages',
        'propertyName' => 'vislanguages'
    ]);

}
```